# Call function so this not needed

Tags: javascript, function

I have an application that uses the v8 javascript engine, and within that I add functions to namespace objects that execute lines of code from the database. The contents of these functions need to not have `this` added before every function call. Following is some example code of my problem

```
var obj = {};
obj.method = function(a) { return a; }
obj.executor = function() { return method(5); }
obj.executor()
ReferenceError: method is not defined

var caller = function() { return method(5); }
caller.call(obj)
ReferenceError: method is not defined
```

As you can see, neither way allows me to call `method` without first adding `this`. Is there some way of executing a function so that it's context is set in such a way that `this` does not need to be added?

*EDIT*

This did work in a previous version of the v8 engine, but it seems the most recent one is not allowing it now.

Comment: No. Why? What's the problem with typing `this.` before the method?

Comment: The client's write rules which are the strings loaded from the database, and it was a requirement (who knows why) that they only need to write the function names and the application sorts out the scoping.

Comment: Only way that would have worked would have been if `obj` was a reference to `window`, or if you were using a `with` statement. Must the functions be methods of an object? Can they be referenced via closure inside a local scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"The client's write rules which are the strings loaded from the database, and it was a requirement (who knows why) that they only need to write the function names and the application sorts out the scoping."*

If you're not running in strict mode, you can use a `with` statement.

```
var obj = {};
obj.method = function(a) { return a; };
obj.executor = function() { 
    with (this) {
        return method(5);
    }
};
obj.executor();
```

```
var caller = function() { 
    with (this) {
        return method(5); 
    }
};

caller.call(obj);
```

Not saying this is a great solution, but it'll work if those are the requirements given.

---

I don't know your other requirements, but you can achieve this via a closure as well.

```
var obj = {};

(function() {
    var method = obj.method = function(a) { return a; };
    obj.executor = function() { 
        return method(5);
    };
}();

obj.executor();
```

Comment: No strict mode, and using `with` works like a charm!

Comment: @Bodyloss: You may want to read up on it a bit if you've not used it before. Because it has some behavior that can catch people off guard, and since it has a negative impact on performance in newer JS engines, people usually avoid it. I added another solution using a closure.

Comment: I had tried closures, but the contents of the executor function is changed before being run each time. It does seem like `with` will be O.K however, as the number of times that a function isn't in the current context is very small.